# How to create a generic type that only works on certain subsets of another type?

Tags: typescript

Assume I have the following type:

```
  type X = 'a' | 'b' | 'c';
```

Now I want to create a generic type

```
  type T<Y extends X> = ...
```

However, `T` should not allow *any* extension of `X` as `Y` but only such extensions that include `'a'`.

That is, `T<Y>` should be okay if `Y = 'a' | 'b'` but not if `Y = 'b' | 'c'`.

How can I change `Y extends X` accordingly?

I tried `Y extends X | 'a'` and `Y extends X & 'a'` but the former would have no effect at all because `'a'` is included in `X` and the latter would be the same as `Y extends 'a'`, i.e. too narrow.

Comment: TypeScript does not have any lower bound constraint (like `Y super "a"`) as requested in [microsoft/TypeScript#14520](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14520). You can get a similar effect like [this](https://tsplay.dev/mZrzem) but could you flesh out your code into a [mre] of where you're going to use this?  There are always possible caveats and it would be nice to see what is being used here.  You should consider just letting `Y` be anything that extends `X` and then use `Y | "a"` instead of `Y` everywhere. But again, I need to see a use case before I can advise futher.

Comment: @jcalz: Ah, thanks. Sometimes I'm just missing the right words. In fact, I thought about using `Y | "a"` everywhere, but in a real world example that may become quite unhandy. I also tried `T<Z extends X, Y = Z | "a">` but it seems that is something different then. My real use case is with generic classes but rather complicated to describe. I will look for a simpler approach then.

Comment: Well, let me know if you want me to write up an answer explaining the above (there is no such constraint, you can kind of simulate it, you can sometimes work around with unions).